# MapReduce Java Program

Tags: mapreduce

In my Map Reduce Java program the TokenizerMapper.java program reports there is a type mismatch. When I am trying to output bigrams from a text document, the above error occurs in the line " String temp = itr.nextToken().toLowerCase(); " to where it reports type mismatch void is assigned to a string. Java code for my mapper method is the following :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;

public class TokenizerMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text,IntWritable> { 
    private final IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text data = new Text();
    public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString(), "-- \t\n\r\f,.:;?![]'\"");
        while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
          String temp = itr.nextToken().toLowerCase();
          if(itr.hasMoreTokens()){
              temp += "," + itr.nextToken().toLowerCase();

          }

          data.set(temp);
          context.write(data, one);
        }
    }
}
```

Can you please help me to resolve the issue? The program did work in a different system but issue arises when I try to run it from Cloudera Virtual machine.

Thank you very much.